# R: apply code equivalent on column-to-column sum nested list

Tags: r, list

```
#Inputs:

n1 = c(5,6,7)
n2 = c(1,2,3)
list1 = data.frame(n1,n2)
list2 = data.frame(n1,n2)
listx = list(list1,list2)


n1 = c(5,6,7,8)
n2 = c(6,7,8,9)
list3 = data.frame(n1,n2)
list4 = data.frame(n1,n2)
list5 = data.frame(n1,n2)
listy = list(list3,list4,list5)


list6 = list(listx,listy)


#Code:

z <- list()
for(i in 1:length(list6)){
  w <- data.frame(x=c(rep(0, nrow(list6[[i]][[1]])))) #init 0,0,0,0...
  for(j in 1:length(list6[[i]])){
    w[,1] <- w[,1] + list6[[i]][[j]]$n1
    z[[i]] <- w
  }  
}
z
```

I believe there's a more efficient coding method instead of using double for-loop, would like lapply/sapply type equivalent (or any?). Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
lapply(list6,function(x) Reduce("+",x)[,1,drop=FALSE])
```

This should do the job given list6.

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`, if there are no missing elements i.e NA, we can use the `reduce` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
list6 %>% 
     map(~ .x %>% 
             reduce(`+`) %>%
             select(1))
```

Or in general, it can be done with `group_by` `sum`

```
list6 %>%
     map(~ bind_rows(.x, .id = 'grp') %>% 
                 group_by(grp) %>%
                 group_by(grp1 = row_number()) %>% 
                 summarise_at(2, sum, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
                 select(-grp1) )
```